# Internal or external Oscillator on STM32F072CBT6

Tags: stm32, embedded

Whats the benefits between internal and external Oscillator?

I'm using a [STM32F072CBT6](http://pdf.datasheetcatalog.com/datasheets/stmicroelectronics/STM32F072C8_STM32F072C8T6_STM32F072C8T6TR_STM32F072C8U7_to_STM32F072VBH6.pdf) and I tried both with internal and external. Dont see any differents.

Can someone explain why I maybe should use an external Oscillator?

Comment: Questions here need to be *specifically answerable* not open-ended.  One could toss out generalities such that an on-chip oscillator is cheaper and often lower power, while one using an external crystal can be more accurate.  But that's not really what this site is about.   What goal are you trying to accomplish for which you might need one not the other?   At a practical level, the "safe" solution is to design your board with an external one and test it, but run your application from the internal if you can and eventually stop populating the external one.

Comment: Worth noting too the accuracy of internal oscillators is far, far better than it was years ago, so usages of them which used to be questionable are now widely standard.

Comment: Maybe you want to run at an oddball, very specific frequency that can only be approximated by the on-chip oscillator?

Comment: I had to add an accurate external oscillator to my STM32L4 design because the internal oscillator was not accurate enough to reliably communicate over UART at 115200 baud rate.  Some devices were fine and other devices were on the edge.  Also changing the board temperature could change the internal oscillator rate enough to throw the comms rate into or out of spec.  The external oscillator resolved all this.

Comment: Is this really too general a question? I can see why asking open ended questions should be discouraged but this particular question seems narrow enough in scope for a good concise answer

Answer (score 3):

External oscillator is more precise than internal oscillator. You use the oscillator that is good enough for the job you are doing. So if the device you are doing does not require high precision, you can choose to make a cheaper product with internal oscillator. If precision of internal oscillator is not enough, then you must use an external oscillator.

For example, interfaces like Ethernet needs 50ppm clock tolerance so an external crystal is required. And you certainly don't want to build an alarm clock with an internal oscillator that has 1% tolerance, it can drift more than 14 minutes a day.

Comment: Additionally, internal oscillator's performance against temperature changes is far worse than any external oscillator's.

Comment: Additionally, STM32F072CBT6 is limited to an internal clock of 64 MHz (as opposed to 72 MHz) and it cannot use the USB peripheral without an external crystal.

Comment: @Codo That's simply wrong. Within first 10 lines of first page of F072 datasheet says among other things "crystal-less USB" and "up to 48 MHz"

Comment: Oops. Yes, I mixed it up with the F1 series. Many of the F0 series indeed run USB nicely without an external clock as I know from my [own design]((https://github.com/manuelbl/usb-serial). They even have a feature to improve clock accuracy based on the 1ms poll from the USB host.